# NX workspace NestJS - loading DTO classes from libraries

Tags: nestjs, nomachine-nx

I have NestJS api in NX workspace.

I created library "model" with user.ts:

```
export interface User{
    name: string
  }

  export interface UserDto extends User {
     email: string
  }
```

user.controller.ts:

```
import { UserDto } from "@project/model";
@Post()
async create(@Req() req, @Res() res, @Body() user: UserDto): Promise<string>{
}
```

I'm getting build error:

> C:\app\project\node_modules@nrwl\node\src\executors\node\node-with-require-overrides.js:16
> return originalLoader.apply(this, arguments);
> ^
> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\app\project\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2015\core.mjs not supported.
> Instead change the require of C:\app\project\node_modules@angular\core\fesm2015\core.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

But this works fine:

```
@Post()
async create(@Req() req, @Res() res): Promise<string>{
    let user: UserDto = <UserDto>{};
}
```

When I created userDTO in NestJS project, it works. How to load entities or DTO from libraries to NestJS? Looks like the fault lies with the decorators.

Thanks

Comment: Anything new about this ? Im having the same issue